# How to perform binary data comparison in Informatica Power Center

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

Please help me on below case.

My source(Oracle db) is having RAW data types and while import those tables into Informatica, RAW datatype are converting automatically into Binary in Informatica.
We need to perform those columns comparions(i.e. Binary = Binary), But not helping us. Please suggest if any ideas.

While i use DECOMPRESS in Informatica, Integration service is not supporting to DECOMPRESS data.

My data looks as 1E49351861F206A09B78005056886094 which is kind ROWID values coming from my Oracle db.

Pl help here. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Informatica misses many operators on Binary data type. You could try with a Java Transformation, where you are free to code whatever you need.

Comment: Can you pl help with some sample java program to compare two binary columns and return status weather those 2 cols are matching or not? Thanks

Comment: iam using below code to compare binary data columns in informatica through JAVA language, but it is always showing error.                         int i;
for(i=1;i<=1;i++)
{
if(src_Binary==Lkp_Binary)
{
 Match="Matching";
}
else
{
 Match="not Matching";
}}